# Динамические поля внутри динамических полей формы HTML и их обработка

Tags: php, javascript, html

Имеется форма, в которой при помощи js реализовано динамическое добавление полей:

```
$(document).on(
    'click',
    '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="add"]',
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
        new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-child').clone();
        new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
        });
        container.append(new_field_group);
    }
);
```

Работает отлично, динамические поля передаю массивами, принимаю скриптом нормально.

```
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="handlers/add_solution.php" method="post">                
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="solution_name" name="solution_name" value="Вариант <?php echo $solutions_num + 1;?>">
        </div>
        <br>
        <h4 class="text-left">Смета затрат на подключение</h4>
        <div data-role="dynamic-fields">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <label for="name">Наименование</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimate_name" name="estimate_name[]" value="">
                <label for="quantity">Количество</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimate_quantity" name="estimate_quantity[]" value="">
                <label for="total">Итог</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimate_total" name="estimate_total[]" value="">                       
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-role="remove">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-role="add">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </div> 
        </div>          
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="comment">Описание</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" class="form-control" value=""></textarea>
                </div>
        </div>  
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ответить" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
    </form>
```

Потребовалось доработать форму - чтобы динамически добавлялись не только поля в блоке "Смета затрат", но и варианты решения. Реализация js должна быть примерно такая, вопрос в том, что поля в блоке "Смета затрат", видимо, должны стать двумерными массивами - первый индекс указание на решение, второй на элемент сметы.
Внимание вопрос - как мне при добавлении копии блока решения прописывать в имя переменной сметы индекс решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать в `input`, на который производится клик, аттрибут, который будет индексом Варианта. Дальше менять имя всех копируемых элементов, меняя в них индексы:

```js
$(document).on(
'click',
'[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="add"]',
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
    var new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-child').clone();
    var solution_num = $(this).attr('data-solution-num');
    new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
        var nameElement = $(this).attr('name');
        $(this).attr('name', nameElement.replace(/(.*)\[(\d)\]/, "$1["+solution_num+"]"));
    });
    container.append(new_field_group);
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="handlers/add_solution.php" method="post">
<?php
++$solutions_num;
?>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="solution_name" name="solution_name" value="Вариант <?=$solutions_num;?>">
        </div>
        <br>
        <h4 class="text-left">Смета затрат на подключение</h4>
        <div data-role="dynamic-fields">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <label for="name">Наименование</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimate_name" name="estimate_name[1][]" value="">
                <label for="quantity">Количество</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimate_quantity" name="estimate_quantity[<?=$solutions_num;?>][]" value="">
                <label for="total">Итог</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimate_total" name="estimate_total[<?=$solutions_num;?>][]" value="">                       
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-role="remove">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-role="add" data-solution-num="<?=$solutions_num;?>">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </div> 
        </div>          
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="comment">Описание</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" class="form-control" value=""></textarea>
                </div>
        </div>  
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ответить" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, разбираюсь. Есть ещё один момент. доработал код под двойное дублирование - https://jsfiddle.net/4kyLg2g1/
Смущает то, что при добавлении строк в новый блок копируется их общее количество. Можно ли как-то без полной переработки скрипта при дублировании блока оставлять только 1 строку? Пока придумал только использовать невидимый  блок, который собственно и копировать при нажатии кнопки...

Comment: На вскидку: можно добавить какой-нибудь аттрибут, и при клонировании его убирать, и выбирать только тех, которые имеют данный аттрибут.
Ещё можно попробовать воспользоваться функцией .map() в jquery и в ней отфильтровать данные

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я уже использую невидимый блок, так оказалось довольно удобно.